# WAIT does not wait for child

Tags: c, fork, wait, pid

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

char *getdir()  /*find working directory*/
{
  char *buffer;/*buffer is going to be used in getcwd function to get the current directory*/
  char *path_buffer;//path_buffer is going to contain the directory//
  long maxsize = pathconf(".", _PC_PATH_MAX);/* we set maxsize as the maximum pathname length*/
  if((buffer=(char*) malloc((size_t)maxsize))!=NULL)
    {
      path_buffer=getcwd(buffer,maxsize); /*get the current directory*/
      printf("\nMy working directory = %s",path_buffer);
      return path_buffer;
    }
  else{
    exit(-1);
  }
}

char * getcmline() /*get command from stdin by the user*/
{
  int bytes_read;
  int nchars=200;/*max possible number for the input of the user*/
  int nbytes=(sizeof(char))*nchars; /*size of chars in bytes*/
  char *line=(char*) malloc(nbytes+1);
  bytes_read=getline(line,&nbytes,stdin);/*read line from stdin*/
  if(bytes_read == -1){
    printf("Read line error");
    exit(-1);
  } /*error handling for bytes_read*/
  else{
    if(line[strlen(line)-1]=='\n')
      {
        line[strlen(line)-1]='\0'; /*change new line character in the end of the line of stdin*/
      }
  }
  return line;
}

int main(void)
{
  pid_t pid,child_pid;
  int rv=0;
  char* exit_string="exit";
  char *path_buffer=NULL;
  int nchars=200;
  int nbytes=(sizeof(char))*nchars;
  char *line=malloc(nbytes+1);
  char *commands[2];
  while(1){
    switch(pid = fork())
      {
      case -1:
        perror("fork"); /* something went wrong */
        exit(1);
      case 0:
        printf(" CHILD: This is the child process!\n");
        child_pid=getpid();
        printf(" CHILD: My PID is %d\n", child_pid);
        path_buffer=getdir();/*get the directory path*/
        line=getcmline();/*get a command by the user*/
        if(strcmp(line,exit_string)==0)
          {
            rv=3;
            exit(rv);
          }
        commands[0]=line;
        commands[1]=NULL;
        execvp(commands[0],commands);
        perror("Execution error");
        exit(-1);



      default:
        waitpid(-1, &rv, 0);
        if(WIFEXITED(rv)){
          printf("Child exited normally and child's exit status is: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(rv));
          if((WEXITSTATUS(rv))==3){
            exit(1);
          }
        }
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I made the changes in `getline`, `rv` and I created a proper variable for `execvp`. But now the error that occurs is that after I type for example "ls". It says:

> execution error: no such file or directory.

thanks again for the help and my lack of knowledge.

the error seems to be in the line variable but i cannot understand whats the problem!

[Char Array and getline in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468994/char-array-and-getline-in-c/12469542?iemail=1#12469542)

The solution was given here.it should be line[(strlen)-1] and not line[(strlen-1)]

Comment: please indent correctly. the logic is difficult to follow, here.

Comment: ingore the code in case 0. it does not matter.

Comment: That's no excuse not to properly indent and format code especially if you want help with it.

Comment: Right, I indented the code for you. What problem are you actually seeing with it?

Comment: Thanks @Useless . I got 5 warnings....
I included them above...

Comment: @ThemisMavridis, please look at how the code is indented now, and how the formatting tools work. If you'd learn to use that properly, this could help you code better :) and help us to help you better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parent never gets the child's pid therefore waitpid is not waiting on it. waitpid(-1,...) will wait for any child processes to finish before continuing.

I would also suggest indenting cases and ending each case statement with a break;

Comment: even with waitpid(-1,&rv,0) or wait(&rv) which is the same, it does not wait. it also changes the value of rv after wait.

Comment: It changes the value of rv after wait but not waitpid()?

Comment: after either wait(&rv) or waitpid(-1,&rv,0) in the default section, the rv value is changed.

Comment: So it DID wait for it? You have a return value don't you?

Answer (score 1):

So, for the warnings: you *know* what lines those numbers refer to, and I'm having to guess: you could make this easier!

```
int rv=NULL;
```

> initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default] line 42

NULL is a pointer value, rv is an integer. Set it to `0` if that's what you mean.

```
execvp(line[0],line);
```

> passing argument 1 of ‘execv’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] line 64
>   passing argument 2 of ‘execv’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] line 64

If you're calling `execv`, the code you're compiling is *not* what you posted. However ... `line` is a `char *`, so `line[0]` is a `char`. The first argument of either `execv` or `execvp` is `const char *`.

What is execv trying to accomplish? It needs a program name to run (first argument, const char *) and an array of arguments (these will form the `argv[]` array passed to the new program's `main` function, and the last item in the array must be NULL).

```
char *line=(char*) malloc(nbytes+1);
bytes_read=getline(&line,&nbytes,stdin);/*read line from stdin*/
```

> passing argument 2 of ‘getline’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] line 29

`getline` needs the address of a buffer to put characters in ... `line` *is* such an address. `&line` however, is the *address of a pointer*. Just take out the `&`.

---

There are more problems in your code, but these warnings all have some things in common:

- you don't seem to understand what types a function expects,
- what types your variables are,
- what types you're actually passing,
- or what the compiler means when it complains your types don't match

You need to understand this *before* you start trying to write multi-process programs. Learn it with something *easy*, learn to read the documentation, and understand the compiler warnings.

Comment: thanks for the help man. so I set
int rv=0;

I create a char* commands[2];
commands[0]=line;
commands[1]=NULL;

but in the getline the warning is in the second argument. And also http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html it says that the first argument is a pointer to a block...

I edited the code again in order to finally get what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Current code looks much better! So now you're successfully building, and at runtime your exec call complains it can't find the program you want it to run. `execvp` should search for it in your `PATH` environment variable - make sure it's in there. `execv` doesn't search the `PATH`, so you need to give an absolute path to the program, eg. `/bin/ls`

Comment: The problem was in if(line[strlen(line-1)]=='\n')
      {
        line[strlen(line-1)]='\0'; /*change new line character in the end of the line of stdin*/
      }

Answer (score 0):

```
default:
waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
//wait(&rv);
printf("PARENT:My child's exit status is: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(rv));
if((WEXITSTATUS(rv))==3){exit(1);}
```

You're passing the uninitialised variable `child_pid` to `waitpid`, that variable is only set in the child process. You should pass `pid`. Using the uninitialised variable causes undefined behaviour, so there's no predicting what will happen. Also you call `WEXITSTATUS` with another uninitialised variable, `rv`, you should pass `status` there.

The child doesn't do anything much here because

```
path_buffer=getcwd(buffer,sizeof(buffer));
```

the size argument passed to `getcwd` is the size of a `char*`, usually four or eight bytes, which is too short for the absolute path of most directories, `path_buffer is set to`NULL`and the child immediately exits. You should pass the size of the buffer,`maxsize` there.

Comment: Edit: Never mind, I'm an idiot. If he passes -1 it will wait for the child process.

Comment: Err, `switch(pid = fork()) {`, `fork` returns the child's PID if it succeeds. Of course `-1` is also a good choice.

Comment: Ah, right, my bad. Forks *still* confuse me if I'm not 100% focused. :P

Comment: I changed status. It was a mistake. rv is the variable in wait. but even with waitpid(-1,...) it does not wait...

Comment: @ThemisMavridis The child immediately exits, see my update, so the `wait` immediately returns.