# Char Array and getline in C

Tags: c, terminal, char, stdin

```
       int bytes_read;
       int rv;
       int nchars = 200;  /*max possible number for the input of the user*/
       size_t nbytes = nchars;  /*size of chars in bytes*/
       char *commands[2];
       char *line = malloc(nbytes + 1);
       bytes_read = getline(&line, &nbytes, stdin);  /*read line from stdin*/
       if (bytes_read == -1) {
           printf("Read line error");
           exit(-1);
       } else {
           if (line[strlen(line-1)] == '\n') {
               line[strlen(line-1)] = '\0';  /*change new line character in the end of the line of stdin*/
           }
       }
       if (strcmp(line,"exit") == 0) {
            rv = 3;
            exit(rv);
       }
       commands[0] = line;
       commands[1] = NULL;
       execvp(commands[0], commands);
       perror("Execution error");
       exit(-1);
```

I have a problem in the code above. If i use `getline` or even `fgets` to get input from the user  from the terminal, and type `"ls"` for example execvp prints that there is "no such file or directory". But If I put `commands[0]="ls"` it runs correctly. What could be the reason?

Comment: At a start, `line[strlen(line-1)]` should be `line[strlen(line)-1]`... Also, please format your code nicely when asking questions on SO.

Comment: What is `getline`? You aren't using C++, since those would be the wrong arguments...please post source for it.

Comment: Thank you @conrad-meyer !and thanks for the tip about the code.

Comment: @nneonneo getline() is totally legit (and preferred) for C. Source: http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html

Comment: It isn't standard C (see [Line Input](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) from the Glibc documentation), but a GNU extension. The parenthesized comment (...at times you will come across compilers that cannot handle the safer getline function.) seems to suggest this.

Comment: Does getline keep the carriage return in the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (line[strlen(line-1)] == '\n') {
    line[strlen(line-1)] = '\0';  /*change new line character in the end of the line of stdin*/
```

That logic to remove the '\n'  looks incorrect. I think it should be:

```
if (line [ strlen(line) - 1 ] == '\n' )
    line [ strlen(line) - 1 ] = '\0';  /*change new line character in the end of the line of stdin*/
```